# Linked List Class in MATLAB - Insert node manually without insertAfter()

Tags: algorithm, matlab, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to use the Linked List Class implementation in MATLAB.
Now, it says the only way to insert a node into the list is by using `insertBefore()` or `insertAfter()`.
But I want to insert the node manually, by specifying the `Next` value of the new node, like

```
newnode = dlnode(new);
ptr.Next = newnode;
newnode.Next=ptrnxt;
```

Would this work? I cannot use the `insertBefore()` or `insertAfter()` in my particular application since I am not maintaining a pointer of the current node.

Details regarding the linked list class is given [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example--implementing-linked-lists.html#brik0u3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that would work with just those three lines of code because it ignores all the other logic that occurs to make sure that the `Next` and `Prev` are set for `newnode` and ignores the update to `ptrnxt` that would need to occur so that its `Prev` is now `newnode`.  (And the `Next` property is private so you would have to change that to public…)

It is unclear by what you mean with *I cannot use the insertBefore() or insertAfter() in my particular application since I am not maintaining a pointer of the current node*.  Yet you have the nodes that you want to insert `newnode` between?  I'm guessing that the order of your nodes (prior to the insertion of the new one) is `…,ptr,ptrnxt,…`.  Then why not just use

```
newnode.insertAfter(ptr);
```

which would change the order to `…,ptr,newnode,ptrnxt,…` and all three properties for each node would be set correctly/automatically.

Else, you would have to change your code to something like

```
newnode      = dlnode(new);
ptr.Next     = newnode;
newnode.Prev = ptr;     % to make sure that newnode points back to ptr
newnode.Next = ptrnxt;
ptrnxt.Prev  = newnode; % to make sure that ptrnxt points back to newnode
```

Much easier and safer to use the `insertAfter` and `insertBefore` methods.

Comment: I believe you are right. I was a bit unclear in my understanding of the underlying code. The implementation is now just fine!